# How to show a button if there are no items in a ListView?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have the following structure:

```
<ScrollView tkMainContent>
  <ListView [items]="students$ | async" class="list-group" *ngIf="students$">
    <ng-template let-student="item">
      <StackLayout>Student details go here</StackLayout>
```

I'm not able to show a button inside the `ScrollView` when there is no student in my list.

How can I still show the button?

Note: I'm testing on a real iOS device.

Comment: Why don't you show the button above the ScrollView when it is empty?

Comment: Tried every possible solution including what you suggested without success! Can you write a piece of code that worked for you?

Comment: I'm actually going to need that for a personal project this afternoon. As soon as I have it I will post an answer here. Hope I find a solution that can help you too.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer below. Hope it saves you some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
                <GridLayout class="page-content" id="placeholderLayout" visibility="{{ hasContent ? 'collapse' : 'visible' }}">
                    <Label class="page-icon fa" text="&#xf030;"></Label>
                    <Label class="page-placeholder" style="white-space: normal" text="Click the camera button to add image"></Label>
                </GridLayout>
                <ScrollView>
                    <-- List View Here -->
                </ScrollView>
            </FlexboxLayout>
```

I use something like this on NS Core, to show placeholder content. The way to set visibility might be different in angular, but a similar markup should work for you.

In the component.ts, you should take care to evaluate if there is content to show in list view, if there are, then set hasContent to true, and false otherwise.

Hope that helps :) let me know if you face any trouble while implementing this.

Comment: Thanks Shiva. Your answer was great. I updated it to replace `GirdLayout` by `FlexLayout` which worked well for me.

Comment: Yeah, you can use your layout of choice, in place of GridLayout in my code sample. :)